# Is there any reason to include both react-app-polyfill and core-js in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dependencies, polyfills, core-js

Does any ReactJS app need **both** react-app-polyfill **and** core-js? If I stick to core-js, can I safely remove react-app-polyfill from the dependencies?